# How do I start a Confidential Compute VM in Azure?

Tags: azure

I tried to start a confidential compute node in Azure through the portal but I keep getting the following error:

`Create MultiVm: failed to parse createUIdefinition file. Error: readyState: 4 responseText: responseXML:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known issue going on where you are unable to deploy 3rd party images in Azure. We expect it to be resolved in within next 5 hours.

Please try again a bit later and if you still see issues let me know.

UPDATE: This issue is resolved.

Comment: Confirmed! I can create the VM now.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. The issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bug on Azure side, since yesterday or so.
Here is a similar issue:
https://community.bitnami.com/t/wordpress-with-azure-database-for-mariadb-azure-template-broken/70984
Also, our team also facing this error.

Comment: Can confirm this appears to be some kind of outage or temporary fault (or a sudden breakage of the API)